# mysql - Delete keyword with link from wordpress post database

Tags: mysql

I have a problem and if anyone can help thanks in advance.

I want to remove some stuffed keyword with link from my wordpress post table example of link

```
<a href="http://example.com/keyword/">keyword</a>
```

I have some posts since 2011 and it`s quite hard to edit all those posts to remove the links....

I wonder if i can use this code `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, '<a href="example.com/keyword/">keyword</a>', '' ) ;`

Any help is most welcome

Regards

Daniel

Comment: As long as the link is the same throughout all of your post content, the SQL query you have should do the trick. I strongly encourage you to make a backup of the `wp_posts` table before taking any action on it. That way if something goes wrong you will have a backup to restore from.

Comment: this only works if your posts content is in the post content. Lots of page builder plugins or fields frameworks will store the data elsewhere

Comment: Yes the links/keyword are between content in each post